# convert a xls file as pdf without poi or jxl

Tags: java

So I summarize my problem. I would like to convert an xls file to PDF, while using java. .
 I find two examples

The first is with Openoffice

```
import officetools.OfficeFile; // from officetools.jar

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("test.doc")); 
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("test.pdf"));

OfficeFile f = new OfficeFile(fis,"localhost","8100", false);

f.convert(fos,"pdf");
```

But unfortunately I have to install it :(

I also find this example, two command line with vb (call pdf creator)

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "repClient", acViewPreview, "NumClient = 2"
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "PDF", "d: \ test.pdf"
```

is there somthing like that on java !!!!
(***Note*** I used for my first solution (jxl, appach poi) but formatting pdf generated is not like when I do save as PDF with Microsoft Excel)

think you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you can stream the data from the excel document using

> apache POI

library. You can pass this stream of data in

> iText library API.

iText library API definitely has a function which writes stream data into PDF file. With iText, you can be sure of pdf formatting as it is widely used in organizations for PDF generation. Infact many reporting tool also use iText to generate PDF reports.

Comment: I useed before ("generate pdf from xls file with iText ") ,just I'm looking on something like these exemple a file input xls then a instrauction and get output file pdf

Comment: FileInputStream input_document = new FileInputStream(new File(path));//this is my file xls
        // Read workbook into HSSFWorkbook
        HSSFWorkbook my_xls_workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(input_document); 
        // Read worksheet into HSSFSheet
        HSSFSheet my_worksheet = my_xls_workbook.getSheetAt(0); 
    
        Document doc= new Document();
        
        PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("D://DEQ//"+selectitem.getRefDeq()+"//Comparatif.pdf"));
        doc.open();
        doc.there is no methode add Stream here!!!